# spring boot redirects to local url

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using spring-boot with spring-security.

```
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
}
```

The problem I have is that when I use:
https://my-domain.com/testPath

instead of redirecting me to https://my-domain.com/login it redirects to
http://10.100.15.40:8541/  (this is its internal IP and port)

here some logs:

```
2019-06-27 08:20:31.031 DEBUG 7 --- [nio-8541-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://10.100.15.40:8541/testPath]
2019-06-27 08:20:31.040 DEBUG 7 --- [nio-8541-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://10.100.15.40:8541/login'
2019-06-27 08:23:50.634 DEBUG 7 --- [nio-8541-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURL: arg1=http://10.100.15.40:8541/testPath; arg2=http://10.100.15.40:8541/testPath (property equals)
2019-06-27 08:23:50.634 DEBUG 7 --- [nio-8541-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : serverName: arg1=10.100.15.40; arg2=10.100.15.40 (property equals)
```

Any one has an idea where can I configure it not to use the internal ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem is. The problem is that the spring application is behind a proxy. And the proxy server did not sent the header X-Forwarded-For. 
To solve it, I needed to configure the proxy server properly.